# get data from SQL using getBytes() in C# (JAVA code is provided)

Tags: java, c#

Just wondering, does anyone know how can I get used of getBytes("test") in C#?

I tried to decompress a result that which have been compressed in Java and save into the database. I have written a code in JAVA and manage to decompress and return result (find below for the JAVA code). Unfortunately, I'm unable to do the same in C#. Does anyone know how could I transfer my JAVA code into C#?

```
/** Generate All Output into One HL7 File **/
public static void generateHL7File(ResultSet rs, String dt, String location)
{
    try {       
        while (rs.next()) {
            String payload= unZIP(rs.getBytes("test"));
        }   
        f.close();  
    } catch ( Exception Ex ) {

    }           
}

/** Unzip string **/
public static String unZIP(byte[] Source) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bins= new ByteArrayInputStream(Source);
    byte[] buf= new byte[2048];
    StringBuffer rString= new StringBuffer("");
    int len;

    try {
        GZIPInputStream zipit= new GZIPInputStream(bins);
        while ((len = zipit.read(buf)) > 0) {
             rString.append(new String(buf).substring(0, len));
        }
        return rString.toString();
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
      return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: @TylerRoper I think he wants byte array blob from SQL. I would just use `Dapper` or if you're using plain ADO.net and a `DataReader` you can `(byte[])reader["test"]`

Answer (score 1):

The similar class of ResultSet in C# is [SqlDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader), it has [GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to read BLOB data. Check the example in the documents.

Translate between JAVA and C# is not a easy work, another idea is using [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_StandardOutput) class to run your JAVA program, and get the result from STDOUT.